# Column check constraint integrity issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle, reference, multiple-columns

```
    SQL> CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
 2  CNUM VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 3  CNAME VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
 4  CTYPE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 5  PRIMARY KEY(CNUM),
 6  CONSTRAINT CHECK (CTYPE IN('INDIVIDUAL', 'INSTITUTION'));
CONSTRAINT CHECK (CTYPE IN('INDIVIDUAL', 'INSTITUTION'))
                                                   *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns
```

Hi, can anyone help with this? I am not referencing any other columns but I receive an error message saying that I am referencing other columns.

Comment: please add a tag for RDBMS used

Comment: Do Oracle constraints require names? I would try changing it to: `CONSTRAINT chk_ctype CHECK (CTYPE IN ('INDIVIDUAL', 'INSTITUTION')));`  I also had to add another right parentheses there, but then it ran ok in SQLFiddle.

Comment: @TomH Thanks bro that was the answer

Comment: Would you like to put it as an answer so i can flag it as the answer

Comment: @TomH You may wish to move the comment to the Answer section...?

Answer (score 4):

I would try changing it to:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_ctype CHECK (CTYPE IN ('INDIVIDUAL', 'INSTITUTION')));
```

I also had to add another right parentheses there, but then it ran ok in SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Constraints in Oracle do NOT require a name.

Rather, EITHER you use the keyword "CONSTRAINT" but in that case you must provide a name, OR you don't use the keyword "CONSTRAINT". The following syntax for your last line works perfectly fine. (Note that after you make this change, you will still get the error message about the missing right parenthesis corresponding to the table definition, as Tom H has noticed.)

```
CHECK (CTYPE IN('INDIVIDUAL', 'INSTITUTION'));
```

That is, if you don't want or need to give the constraint a name, just DELETE the word "CONSTRAINT" from that line.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#CJAGIICD